# What would be a good Gmail filter for deleting survey requests?

Tags: gmail-filters

I receive a large number of survey requests from a variety of companies that I've done business with. I did not opt in for any of these surveys, but almost every business I interact with online sends me invitations to complete a survey. If I delete the email, they have timer that schedules an infinite number of reminder emails, letting me know that I did not yet complete their survey.

This cannot be a new problem, so I've searched (Google'd) for solutions that others have used, and did not find any.

The senders are my apartment complex, pizza delivery, zipper , hertz... any company that I have interacted with.

Comment: Don't they have the `unsubscribe` option at the end of each email?